# javascript modify document without getting previous state stored to undo buffer

Tags: javascript, iframe, paste, undo

I wonder, Is it possible to modify a, let say, iframe inner document without having its previous state saved on undo buffer. I have a little WYSIWIG editor, which removes unsupported formatting from pasted text like this : first, the 'paste' event is caught, then it stores original caret position, waits until the text is pasted, gets new InnerHtml value, filters everything, starting from the saved caret position and assigns new InnerHtml value to the body of iframe. But when the user clicks 'undo' from the context menu, the modification to iframe body InnerHtml is discarded, and the nasty original text with all unsupported tags is there again. Is there something, that can be done, other than throwing out another textarea, asking user to paste there and copying sanitized text back to iframe ?